# Change coupon email restriction after successful purchase in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to essentially restrict a coupon code to the user who applied it in Woocommerce after their first purchase.

What I have so far:

```
    function change_meta_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if( $order->get_used_coupons() ) {

    update_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'customer_email', $emailrestrict );

        }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'change_meta_on_purchase' );
```

I think I must be wrong in "get_used_coupons" but I need the coupon they used to be the one that gets restricted.

Comment: You want that a customer can only use the coupon once ?

Comment: no limit on usage, just a limit on who can use it

Comment: So you want that the user can use one particular coupon juste for the first order ?

Comment: i want the customer to use that coupon and then woocommerce restricts that coupon to that customer after they have used it, changing the email_restriction metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right and modern way using Woocommerce version 3+ [CRUD setters and getters methods](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/the-new-crud-classes-in-woocommerce-2-7/) to set customer email as email restrictions for coupons used when order get a "processing" status:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'coupon_email_restriction_on_purchase', 20, 2 );
function coupon_email_restriction_on_purchase( $order_id, $order ) {
    $applied_coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();
    if( count( $applied_coupons ) == 0 )
        return; // Exit if there is no coupons

    // Get the Customer billing email
    $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();

    foreach( $applied_coupons as $coupon_code ){
        // Get an instance of the WC_Coupon object
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );

        // Get email restrictions (even if is an empty array)
        $email_restrictions = $coupon->get_email_restrictions();
        // Add the customer email to the restrictions array
        $email_restrictions[] = $customer_email;
        // set the new array of email restrictions
        $coupon->set_email_restrictions( $email_restrictions );

        // Save the coupon data
        $coupon->save();
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

This should works.